# C - can't access global variable within user functions

Tags: c

can anyone tell how in C access global variable (in my example it's array 'used') within user functions (in my example it's 'checkData')? it c++ similar code works (but I used 'used = new bool[size];' instead of 'bool used[size];')

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define true 1
#define false 0

typedef int bool;
bool *used;
int i;

void checkData(int i);

int main ()
{
    int size = 10;

    bool used[size];
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        used[i] = false;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        checkData(i);

    return 0;
}

void checkData(int i) {
    printf("%d - %d\n", i, used[i]);
}
```

Comment: Your `checkData` function already accesses the global variable `used`. It's just not getting the values you expect because the `main` function is *not* accessing the same global variable. `main` declares a *local* variable, `bool used[size];` and sets that instead.

Comment: or `void checkData(int i, int used[], size_t len)` and keep your local in `main()` passing it and its size to your function.

Comment: Don't define your own boolean type. Use the standard type with `stdbool.h`. And `used` is a pointer, not an array!

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: This is not the first nor the last question to use wrong tags (_sigh_)

Comment: I write code not in c++ but in C. I just mentioned how that would work in c++ (i know that c++ has bool type but didn't mention it)

Comment: @Alexandr: No, I talk about C. C has a boolean type, too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `used` is a duplicated name. In `main` the local `used` is accessed. But in `checkData` the global instance is used, but causes an error since you are dereferencing a `NULL` pointer (static variables are initialised to `0`).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that used is an array? 
Syntax for array of type int for 10 members is for example:

```
int used[10];
```

Note: in function checkdata you access the int pointer used not the array

Answer (score 0):

`bool used[size];`

is a local variable in `main()` which hides the `used` variable name at the global scope,so your main function does not "see" `bool* used`. when you access used in main you are not accessing the global variable `bool* used`. Your `checkData()` function access the global variable which is not the same as the one you created in `main()`.

Comment: ok. but how can i access in checkData() variable (used[]) that was set in main() ? (but without passing used[] as argument from main() )

Comment: This is about C, not C++!

Comment: @Alexandr: There is a good reason "local" variables are not called "global" variables.